# php mail() working on terminal but not in browser

Tags: php, macos, apache, php-5.6

I have a small php test script with the following code:

```
if (mail("test@test.com", "Subject", "Message", "From:test@test.com")) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'failur';
}
```

When I run the script in the terminal like this:

```
php test.php
```

It prints 'OK' but when I open it on my lokal apache via localhost/test.php is says 'failur'.

I also hava a file with phpinfo() in it and the browser and terminal are using the same php version and the same php.ini file.

I can't think of a apache configuration that would prevent mail from working.

Apache 2.4.18 (Mac)
PHP 5.6.23 (installed via homebrew)

Comment: One difference that comes to mind is the user running it (you in the terminal vs the user running your web server). Does it work if run as your web server user in that user's envionment? (That would be something like `sudo -u www-data php test.php` on Linux.)

Comment: in both cases through local environment mail will not send. And if i put your code at my end and run through browser. it prints `ok`

Comment: @lengyelg apache is set up to run as the same user as my current user.

Comment: @Anant I have running mailcatcher on my system and via php it catches the mail but via the browser it gives 'failur' and mailcatcher also gets no mail. I can only asume that it is some kind of apache config I have set wrong or something else the apache can not find/execute